# Deserializing JSON string as JavaScript date

Tags: javascript, json

I received the following json:

```
    [
      {
       time: "2019-05-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      }
    ]
```

Now my paragraph renders as

```
<p>2019-03-31T22:00:00.000Z</p>
```

How can I retrieve the date and the time so that it will look like something more readable?

```
<p>31 May 2019. Time: 22:00</p>
```

Comment: Have a look at the Date() Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript Date object. e.g.

const myDate = new Date('2019-05-31T22:00:00.000Z');

Then you can perform things like myDate.toDateString() which would give "Fri May 31 2019"

All of the other date functions are listed here which might help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways you can do it with the Date object. `time.toDateString()` probably being the easiest but obviously opinionated.

Otherwise you can display it how you want using `time.getFullYear()` and `time.getDay()` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Moment-Timezone library helps you to convert date/time format to various format.

Usage: `moment('2019-03-31T22:00:00.000Z').format('DD MMM YYYY[.] [Time:] kk:mm')`